# can't format memory card

Tags: linux, partitioning, sd-card

I have a 64GB SanDisk SD card which can't be written in any kind. Neither file operations (exFat filesystem) nor partition table operations (create new partition table etc.) have any effect. But, weirdly, no error messages appear as well (neither in file manager nor in terminal). Instead, every change seems fine, but gets lost as soon as the device is removed. Tried gparted, parted as well, same behaviour. Dmesg doesn't mention something suspicious:

```
[ 1745.157286] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[ 1745.297481] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1745.301922] scsi host1: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[ 1746.437194] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multiple Card  Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 1747.215991] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 124735488 512-byte logical blocks: (63.9 GB/59.5 GiB)
[ 1747.217152] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1747.217165] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 1747.218239] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 1747.218253] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1747.227264]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1747.231661] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1758.281234] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 11
```

The write lock switch on the SD card is off. When turned on, parted recognizes the disk as read-only, so it seems to work.

Any ideas for further diagnostics?

Comment: Is the SD card healthy?

Comment: What do you mean by healthy? It is not old and wasn’t used much.